# How to move my app from "Rejected" status to "waiting for upload" status?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes, app-store-connect

my app was rejected from my iTunesConnect account and now i did't find ready for upload button on iTunesConnect new design. so how can my app move from "Rejected" status to waiting for upload status.

Answer (score 2):

thanks to all this issue solved.
now in [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/) new design this steps are changed as below.

Step 1 : first you need to upload new build from XCode or Application Loader.

Step 2 : open [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/) account and Then Attach that build on [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/) build section.

Step 3 : then click on save button.

Step 4 :Click on Right Side You have Option to Submit For Review.

so by following these steps your app move from **"Rejected"** status to **"Waiting for review Status"**.